# how can i keep original pdf font style after translate pdf

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I want to translate pdf content and generate the translated pdf file. i choose pdfbox to create new translated pdf file, It need to keep the original layout and style. I can get the font size, color and style. i can get all words or paragraphs, and then call google translate service api,at last create new tranlated pdf file by pdfbox. The problem is how to keep the original style in new pdf file.

Comment: Are your original files tagged with style information?

Comment: "... keep the original layout..." How can you keep the original layout in the cases where the translated text is longer or shorter than the original text? Especially if the translated text is longer, I would imagine your text would run off edge of the page, or occlude adjacent text. Wouldn't you want to have reflow?

Comment: @mkl original file was not tagged.

Comment: In that case recognizing paragraphs, layout, and some style details becomes (educated) guesswork. There are a number of scientific papers on heuristics for this. You may want to study them and apply these techniques. With the results you can extract text of the recognized paragraphs, translate it, and build a translated document with similar layout and style.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for you help. I will try to read some papers.